# Cordova app with Universal Windows 10 platform fails to send analytics logs

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

I have been trying to send logs from a Cordova app with the Universal Windows 10 platform to MobileFirst Server 8.0.

The JavaScript console printed out following message:

> [http://192.168.10.120:9080/mfp/apps/services/loguploader] failure. state: 404, response: The server was unable to process the request from the application. Please try again later.

Did I miss out some JNDI properties (I am using the default properties here) on the MobileFirst server?

Comment: Are the rest of the calls working? WLResourceRequest and other calls?

Comment: Yes, they are working fine. That loguploader URL above works fine when I send logs using native Android application. Furthermore, when I tried the codes from (https://github.com/ynunez/MobileFirstAnalyticsSender), I got an Unsupported Media Type response. Does the application have to be registered into Analytics server before the logs could appear?

Comment: That application is not meant for v8.0...

Comment: That URL was given to me by an IBM staff. Since this doesn't work in v8.0, is there another way to send analytics logs from Cordova or does this supposed to not work on a Windows phone emulator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the documentation, MobileFirst Operational Analytics in MobileFirst Foundation 8.0 currently does not support Windows 8.1 Universal or Windows 10 UWP in native or Cordova apps:  https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/analytics/

My suggestion would be to open an RFE for the product managers to consider for future releases: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/